# auto submit input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heres the link to https://jsfiddle.net/6jb2g1ff/7/

I have a blog in squarespace and use Swiftype to make the search.

when i search 100 or more it works, and the result popps up.

When i search 1-99 nothing comes up.

Any inputs?

Html:

```
<input type="text" class="st-default-search-input" placeholder="Eksempel : 1. Ola Normann">
<div class="st-search-container"></div>
```

css:

```
.st-ui-type-detail {
display:none!important;
}   
.st-ui-pagination-link {
display:none!important;
}
.st-ui-injected-search-summary {
display:none!important;
}
.st-default-search-input {
padding: 24px 24px 24px 45px!important;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px #8a1b04!important;
border:solid 1px black!important;
border-radius:1px!important;
opacity:1!important;
font-weight:300!important;
font-family:"Open Sans"!important;
}
.st-ui-search-input, .st-default-search-input {
display: inline-block!important;
width:600px!important;
font-weight: 300!important;
color: #444!important;
font-size: 16px!important;
line-height: 26px!important;
box-sizing: content-box!important;
background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/564c80e3e4b0b8eaceab5e6b/t/564c8a99e4b06a24968e9467/1447856793834/iconmonstr-magnifier-4-icon-256.png)!important;
background-size:30px 30px!important;
background-position: .5% 50%!important;
background-repeat:no-repeat!important;
background-clip: padding-box!important;
}
.st-query-present a {
background-color:white!important;
margin-top:-30px!important;
transition:1000ms!important;
}
.st-query-present a {
margin-top:3px!important;
padding:50px!important;
width:567px!important;
border-radius:0px!important;
border-bottom: solid 2px #eac06b!important;
border-left: solid 2px #eac06b!important;
border-right: solid 2px #eac06b!important;
transition:1000ms!important;
}
a.st-ui-result:before {
display:none!important;
}
```

javascript:

```
(function (w, d, t, u, n, s, e) {
w['SwiftypeObject'] = n;
w[n] = w[n] || function () {
    (w[n].q = w[n].q || []).push(arguments);
};
s = d.createElement(t);
e = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
s.async = 1;
s.src = u;
e.parentNode.insertBefore(s, e);
})(window, document, 'script', '//s.swiftypecdn.com/install/v2/st.js', '_st');

_st('install', '54uesUyrnHtyKyxziyes', '2.0.0');
```

Comment: by the way. you are not using jquery and you are not using java

Comment: Oh im sorry, was written a bit to fast i suppose.

I mean that from 1-99 it wont auto-submit, so i do not get the search result up automaticly, but at 100 and more i do get it automaticly.